# Magento 2 - Add Static page to navigation

Tags: magento, magento2

I'm working on a store in Magento 2. It's based on the Magento Luma theme.

But now i'm kinda stuck - how do i add static cms pages to the navigation along with the store categories?

Answer (score 1):

Please write code in default.xml file on below location-

```
vendor/magento/module-theme/view/frontend/layout
```

Now replace Static Cms page name and Url by your page name and url.

```
<referenceContainer name="catalog.topnav">
               <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" name="your.link">
                    <arguments>
                        <argument name="label" xsi:type="string">Link-name</argument>
                        <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">Link-url</argument>
                    </arguments>
              </block> 
</referenceContainer>
```

Comment: When I do this the new styling on the "Link-name" is weird (It's underneath the other links, not floating next to links. If I add class "level0" it looks better, but adding class to arguments list doesn't work). Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

**Magento2 add a cms page link to menu or Magento2 add a custom link to the menu,**

**First**, *create a module*.

**files**:

- `app\code\{VendorName}\{ModuleName}\etc\module.xml`
- `app\code\{VendorName}\{ModuleName}\registration.php`
- `app\code\{VendorName}\{ModuleName}\composer.json`

**Second**: *create **di.xml** where  we will define plugin*

> ```
> app\code\{VendorName}\{ModuleName}\etc\di.xml
> ```

**code is**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Topmenu">
        <plugin name="add_cms_menu" type="{VendorName}{ModuleName}\Plugin\Topmenu" sortOrder="1" />
    </type>
</config>
```

**Third**: *create **di.xml** where  we will define plugin*

> ```
> app\code\{VendorName}\{ModuleName}\Plugin\Topmenu.php
> ```

***Code is***

```
<?php 
namespace {VendorName}{ModuleName}\Plugin;
use Magento\Framework\Data\Tree\NodeFactory;
class Topmenu
{
    protected $nodeFactory;
    protected $_storeManager;
    protected $_pageFactory;
    protected $_urlBuilder;

    public function __construct(
        NodeFactory $nodeFactory,
        \Magento\Cms\Model\PageFactory $pageFactory,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Framework\UrlInterface $urlBuilder
    ) {
        $this->nodeFactory = $nodeFactory;
        $this->_pageFactory = $pageFactory;
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->_urlBuilder = $urlBuilder;
    }
    public function beforeGetHtml(
        \Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Topmenu $subject,
        $outermostClass = '',
        $childrenWrapClass = '',
        $limit = 0
    ) {
        /* Showing  Cms page About us at menu */
        $page = $this->getCmspage('about-us');
        if($page == null){
            return;
        }


        $node = $this->nodeFactory->create(
            [
                'data' => [
                    'name' => $page->getTitle(),
                    'id' => $page->getIdentifier(),
                    'url' =>  $this->_urlBuilder->getUrl(null, ['_direct' => $page->getIdentifier()]),
                    'has_active' => false,
                    'is_active' => false // (expression to determine if menu item is selected or not)
                ],
                'idField' => 'id',
                'tree' => $subject->getMenu()->getTree()
            ]
        );
        $subject->getMenu()->addChild($node);
    }
    protected function getCmspage($identifier){

        $page = $this->_pageFactory->create();
        $pageId = $page->checkIdentifier($identifier, $this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId());

        if (!$pageId) {
            return null;
        }
        $page->setStoreId($this->_storeManager->getStore()->getId());
        if (!$page->load($pageId)) {
            return null;
        }

        if (!$page->getId()) {
            return null;
        }

        return $page;
    }

}
```

More details checkout out at

http://www.amitbera.com/magento2-add-a-cms-page-link-to-menu/

Answer (score 0):

Want to add a link to the top navigation within `<header>`
Adding a link to CMS page, Gallery

Edit/Place default.xml here:

```
app/design/frontend/Vendor/theme/Magento_Theme/layout/default.xml
```

Add the following code:

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="catalog.topnav">
           <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" name="gallery.link">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="label" xsi:type="string">Gallery</argument>
                    <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">gallery</argument>
                </arguments>
          </block> 
       </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

This adds a link to CMS page, Gallery, with the following settings:

```
Title = Gallery
Url Key = gallery
Link = https://example.com/gallery/
```

Add the following styling to ensure the new link aligns correctly:

```
.navigation .nav.item {
margin: 0 10px 0 0;
display: inline-block;
position: relative;
}
```

[image: Results of the code]
(Products is setup as a category for an example)